# Error while call multiple animated sprite

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Here I created several classes for each sprite. Examples are `DeviceOne` and `DeviceTwo`. All went well when only creating and loading 1 sprite. However when I call `DeviceTwo` and reload dataVizExtension I always get the following error.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dbId')`

This is the code for DeviceOne, basically class for DeviceTwo is same. The different only the sprite images.

```
export class DeviceOne {
  constructor(viewer, dataVizExtn) {
    this.viewer = viewer;
    this.dataVizExtn = null;
    this.DataVizCore = null;
    this.viewableType = null;
    this.viewableData = null;

    this.baseURL = "http://localhost:3000/assets/images/sprite/";

    this.sensorPositions = {
      Dasloop: {
        x: 10,
        y: -3,
        z: 20,
      },
      Warning: {
        x: 0,
        y: 10,
        z: 3,
      },
    };
    this.dasloops = [
      "img_gps_dasloop_online.svg",
      "img_gps_dasloop_online-1.svg",
      "img_gps_dasloop_online-2.svg",
      "img_gps_dasloop_online-3.svg",
    ];

    this.warnings = ["ic_warning.svg", "ic_warning-2.svg"];

    this.startAnim1 = 0;
    this.startAnim2 = 0;
    this.startAnim3 = 0;
    this.infoChart = new InfoChart(this.viewer, this.options);
  }

  /**
   * @return {ViewableData} resulting viable data that contains all viewables (icons)
   */

  async onSpriteLoadedToScene() {
    this.dataVizExtn = await this.viewer.loadExtension(
      "Autodesk.DataVisualization"
    );
    const dataVizCore = Autodesk.DataVisualization.Core;
    this.onSpriteHovering = this.onSpriteHovering.bind(this);
    this.viewer.addEventListener(
      dataVizCore.MOUSE_HOVERING,
      this.onSpriteHovering
    );

    this.onSpriteClicked = this.onSpriteClicked.bind(this);
    this.viewer.addEventListener(dataVizCore.MOUSE_CLICK, this.onSpriteClicked);

    const viewableType = dataVizCore.ViewableType.SPRITE;
    const spriteColor = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    const highlightedColor = new THREE.Color(0xe0e0ff);
    const spriteIconUrl = `${this.baseURL}${"img_gps_dasloop_online.svg"}`;

    const dasloopStyles = new dataVizCore.ViewableStyle(
      viewableType,
      spriteColor,
      spriteIconUrl,
      highlightedColor,
      `${this.baseURL}${this.dasloops[0]}`,
      this.dasloops.map((dasloop) => `${this.baseURL}${dasloop}`)
    );

    const warningStyles = new dataVizCore.ViewableStyle(
      viewableType,
      spriteColor,
      `${this.baseURL}${"ic_warning.svg"}`,
      highlightedColor,
      `${this.baseURL}${this.warnings[0]}`,
      this.warnings.map((warning) => `${this.baseURL}${warning}`)
    );
    this.viewableData = new dataVizCore.ViewableData();
    this.viewableData.spriteSize = 30;

    const simulationData = [
      { position: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 10 } },
      { position: { x: 5, y: -3, z: 10 } },
    ];
    const warningData = [{ position: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 } }];

    simulationData.forEach((myData, index) => {
      const dbId = 10 + index;
      const position = myData.position;
      const viewable = new dataVizCore.SpriteViewable(
        position,
        dasloopStyles,
        dbId
      );

      this.viewableData.addViewable(viewable);
    });

    warningData.forEach((myData, index) => {
      const dbId = 15 + index;
      const position = myData.position;
      const viewableWarning = new dataVizCore.SpriteViewable(
        position,
        warningStyles,
        dbId
      );
      this.viewableData.addViewable(viewableWarning);
    });

    await this.viewableData.finish();
    this.dataVizExtn.addViewables(this.viewableData);

    this.spriteToUpdate = this.dataVizExtn.viewableData.viewables.map(
      (sprite) => sprite.dbId
    );

    this.animate = setInterval(this.getAnimateSprite.bind(this), 500);
  }

  getAnimateSprite() {
    this.dataVizExtn.invalidateViewables(this.spriteToUpdate, (viewable) => {
      switch (viewable.dbId) {
        case 10:
          return {
            url: `${this.baseURL}${
              this.dasloops[this.startAnim1++ % this.dasloops.length]
            }`,
          };
        case 15:
          return {
            url: `${this.baseURL}${
              this.warnings[this.startAnim2++ % this.warnings.length]
            }`,
          };
        case 11:
          return {
            url: `${this.baseURL}${
              this.dasloops[this.startAnim3++ % this.dasloops.length]
            }`,
          };
        default:
          break;
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's a little hard for me to tell where the error came from with the above code snippet, but you mentioned `reload dataVizExtension`. So, I would advise you to check your `this.animate = setInterval(this.getAnimateSprite.bind(this), 500);`.

Did you clear the `setInterval` call by `clearInterval(this.animate)` while unloading and before reloading your extension?